# Unable to locate mono packages in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, package-management, mono

After updating Linux with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I'm trying to install **referenceassemblies-pcl** and **ca-certificates-mono** as per [this article](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#usage) respectively using the below commands:

```
sudo apt-get install referenceassemblies-pcl
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-mono
```

The command looks correct, as per [ziyasal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805245/how-to-solve-xbuild-netportable-version-v4-0-profile-profile344-issue-on-linu/27823034#27823034) but I'm getting these errors:

> `unable to locate package referenceassemblies-pcl`
>
> `unable to locate package ca-certificates-mono`

The outputs of

```
apt-cache policy ca-certificates-mono

apt-cache policy referenceassemblies-pcl
```

respectively are

> `Unable to locate package ca-certificates-mono`
>
> `Unable to locate package referenceassemblies-pcl`

The output of `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:referenceassemblies-pci/ppa` is:

> Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:referenceassemblies-pci/ppa'.
>
> Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.

The output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list`

> `cat: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list: No such file or directory`

**Quesion:** What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [Edit] you question and add the output of `apt-cache policy ca-certificates-mono` and `apt-cache policy referenceassemblies-pcl`

Comment: Add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list`

Comment: cat: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list: No such file or directory

Comment: OK. I assume, that are also no other `*xamarin*` files in this folder. Follow the steps in my answer exactly and post the error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All works great. I assume, you forgot

```
sudo apt-get update
```

---

or simply start all steps again:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin*
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
```

---

```
% apt-cache policy referenceassemblies-pcl
referenceassemblies-pcl:
  Installed: 2014.04.14-1
  Candidate: 2014.04.14-1
  Version table:
 *** 2014.04.14-1 0
        500 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

% apt-cache policy mono-complete          
mono-complete:
  Installed: 4.0.2.5-0xamarin1
  Candidate: 4.0.2.5-0xamarin1
  Version table:
 *** 4.0.2.5-0xamarin1 0
        500 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu4 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe i386 Packages

% apt-cache policy mono-complete          
mono-complete:
  Installed: 4.0.2.5-0xamarin1
  Candidate: 4.0.2.5-0xamarin1
  Version table:
 *** 4.0.2.5-0xamarin1 0
        500 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu4 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe i386 Packages

% apt-cache policy ca-certificates-mono
ca-certificates-mono:
  Installed: 4.0.2.5-0xamarin1
  Candidate: 4.0.2.5-0xamarin1
  Version table:
 *** 4.0.2.5-0xamarin1 0
        500 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: I believe I did it. [The article asked to update.](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/) Let me again give it a try.

Comment: @BountyMan: If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: @Fabby - +1 for all answers

Comment: @BountyMan  **:D** I'm not the poster, but anyway: you know the drill from StackOverflow: if it works, accept...  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby - It's not working mann. I am pulling my hair because I have already done this before in the same machine. I uninstalled and reinstalled everything but why it is not happening now is my problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you tryed this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:referenceassemblies-pci/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install referenceassemblies-pci
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:referenceassemblies-pci/Ubuntu'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.

Comment: @BountyMan `ppa:referenceassemblies-pci/ppa` and **not** `ppa:referenceassemblies-pci/Ubuntu`

Answer (score 1):

The `echo` command to write to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list` might not work in your case. I had similar error when piping commands to a docker image - reported here (https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8679).

In that case the solution to pipe to docker instead:

```
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | docker exec -i --user=root MyContainer tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
```

If this is not the case, you could perhaps just write the file with the missing line in other ways.

Comment: For clueless users: Despite the URL is specifying `/debian wheezy`, it is valid for Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives according to [this documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives).

Comment: @clearkimura and Keld - I have stopped working on linux from a while. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem as what you say.
But I found the reason at last:
    I shouldn't use the ctrl+c and ctrl+v to run the three commands at a time:

```
1.sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
2.echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
3.sudo apt-get update
```

In this way,there are actually only first command is excuted.
So I run there command one by one,and the problem solved.

Comment: Although my problem is solved already, Thank you for your efforts. :)